# How to determine the byte length of a long

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a fast way to determine the number of bytes used in a long? I'm looking for something like this:

```
len((1000**1000).to_bytes())
```

(The problem of course is that `to_bytes` wants the number of bytes as input.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(x.bit_length() + 7) // 8` will do what you want. Number of bits, converted to bytes and rounded up.